# Dbus-send how to get the number of pages from zathura?

Tags: linux, bash, ipc, gnome, dbus

I am trying to use `dbus-send` to get the total number of page from zathura (Zathura is a PDF viewer) (See figure below). I am not familiar with DBus (no matter how I try to learn it, I always give up).

I could use a GUI program to see the total number of pages `numberofpages` when I double click on that property I get the value.

However, I am trying to get the same information using `dbus-send`. I tried the following on the terminal:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.pwmt.zathura.PID-1057698 \
 --print-reply org.pwmt.zathura.Properties.numberofpages
```

The command above doesn't work.

Could you please tell me how can I construct a dbus-command to get the `numberofpages` value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easier to do using `busctl` rather than `dbus-send`. Either way there is four bits of information you need to know for most D-Bus situation.

1. Bus Name: `org.pwmt.zathura.PID-1057698`
2. Path: `/org/pwmt/zathura`
3. Interface: `org.pwmt.zathura`
4. Property: `numberofpages`

I would expect your situation to look like:

```
busctl --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-1057698 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura numberofpages
```

To try this on a service that is likely to be running on most machines:

1. Bus Name: `org.freedesktop.systemd1`
2. Path: `/org/freedesktop/systemd1`
3. Interface: `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager`
4. Property: `Architecture`

And to run it with both utilities:

**dbus-send**

```
$ dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get string:"org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager" string:"Architecture"
method return time=1650033765.273653 sender=:1.0 -> destination=:1.176 serial=2677 reply_serial=2
   variant       string "x86-64"
```

**busctl**

```
$ busctl --user get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager Architecture 
s "x86-64"
```

Comment: In the first command, and in the path why are you using `/org/pwmt/zathura1` instead of `/org/pwmt/zathura` ?

Comment: It was a typo. I don't have Zathura installed so I had no way of testing it and I had copied it wrong from your image. I've updated the answer. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling with `dbus-send` command, finally I found the right syntax:

```
dbus-send --session  --print-reply \
 --dest=org.pwmt.zathura.PID-1057698\ 
 /org/pwmt/zathura \
 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get \
 string:org.pwmt.zathura string:numberofpages
```

The output of that command is:

```
method return time=1650032068.076028 sender=:1.2273 -> destination=:1.2408 serial=79 reply_serial=2
   variant       uint32 46
```

I can use grep to get the value `46` (which is in my case the total number of pages in the PDF document).

Comment: As an alternative you may want to look at using the `busctl` tool as it seems easier syntax to me.

Comment: @ukBaz: Thank you for letting me know about that utility. Could you please add an answer using it?